# setmainfont fails on not available font despite font being available

Tags: fonts, fontspec, installing-fonts

I've the following *IBM Plex* font available in my font user directory, which is correctly identified when using `fc-list`:

```
fc-list | grep -i IBMPlexSans
```

produces:

```
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-SemiBoldItalic.ttf: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans SemiBold:style=SemiBold Italic,Italic
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-Regular-Latin1.woff: IBM Plex Sans:style=Regular
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-Light.otf: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans Light:style=Light,Regular
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-Regular-Latin3.woff: IBM Plex Sans:style=Regular
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-Regular-Latin2.woff: IBM Plex Sans:style=Regular
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-Thin.otf: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans Thin:style=Thin,Regular
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-Medium.ttf: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans Medium:style=Medium,Regular
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-SemiBold-Latin2.woff: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans SemiBold:style=SemiBold,Regular
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-SemiBold-Latin3.woff: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans SemiBold:style=SemiBold,Regular
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-SemiBold-Latin1.woff: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans SemiBold:style=SemiBold,Regular
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-SemiBold.ttf: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans SemiBold:style=SemiBold,Regular
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-Regular.ttf: IBM Plex Sans:style=Regular
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-SemiBoldItalic-Pi.woff: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans SemiBold:style=SemiBold Italic,Italic
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-Text.ttf: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans Text:style=Text,Regular
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-ExtraLightItalic.otf: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans ExtraLight:style=ExtraLight Italic,Italic
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-Regular-Pi.woff: IBM Plex Sans:style=Regular
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-TextItalic.otf: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans Text:style=Text Italic,Italic
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-Regular.otf: IBM Plex Sans:style=Regular
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-SemiBoldItalic-Latin1.woff: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans SemiBold:style=SemiBold Italic,Italic
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-SemiBoldItalic-Latin3.woff: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans SemiBold:style=SemiBold Italic,Italic
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-SemiBoldItalic-Latin2.woff: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans SemiBold:style=SemiBold Italic,Italic
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-Bold.ttf: IBM Plex Sans:style=Bold
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-ExtraLightItalic.ttf: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans ExtraLight:style=ExtraLight Italic,Italic
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-ExtraLight.ttf: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans ExtraLight:style=ExtraLight,Regular
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-Text.otf: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans Text:style=Text,Regular
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-TextItalic.ttf: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans Text:style=Text Italic,Italic
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-LightItalic-Pi.woff: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans Light:style=Light Italic,Italic
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-MediumItalic.ttf: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans Medium:style=Medium Italic,Italic
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-LightItalic-Latin3.woff: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans Light:style=Light Italic,Italic
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-LightItalic-Latin2.woff: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans Light:style=Light Italic,Italic
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-LightItalic-Latin1.woff: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans Light:style=Light Italic,Italic
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-Italic.ttf: IBM Plex Sans:style=Italic
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-BoldItalic.ttf: IBM Plex Sans:style=Bold Italic
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-LightItalic.otf: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans Light:style=Light Italic,Italic
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-MediumItalic.otf: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans Medium:style=Medium Italic,Italic
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-Light-Pi.woff: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans Light:style=Light,Regular
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-Medium.otf: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans Medium:style=Medium,Regular
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-ThinItalic.ttf: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans Thin:style=Thin Italic,Italic
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-Italic.otf: IBM Plex Sans:style=Italic
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-Bold.otf: IBM Plex Sans:style=Bold
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-ExtraLight.otf: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans ExtraLight:style=ExtraLight,Regular
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-Italic-Latin1.woff: IBM Plex Sans:style=Italic
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-Italic-Latin2.woff: IBM Plex Sans:style=Italic
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-Italic-Latin3.woff: IBM Plex Sans:style=Italic
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-SemiBoldItalic.otf: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans SemiBold:style=SemiBold Italic,Italic
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-SemiBold-Pi.woff: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans SemiBold:style=SemiBold,Regular
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-ThinItalic.otf: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans Thin:style=Thin Italic,Italic
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-LightItalic.ttf: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans Light:style=Light Italic,Italic
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-Light.ttf: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans Light:style=Light,Regular
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-Light-Latin3.woff: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans Light:style=Light,Regular
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-Light-Latin2.woff: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans Light:style=Light,Regular
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-Thin.ttf: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans Thin:style=Thin,Regular
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-BoldItalic.otf: IBM Plex Sans:style=Bold Italic
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-Light-Latin1.woff: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans Light:style=Light,Regular
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-Italic-Pi.woff: IBM Plex Sans:style=Italic
/myPath/myPath/myUsername/.fonts/IBMPlexSans-SemiBold.otf: IBM Plex Sans,IBM Plex Sans SemiBold:style=SemiBold,Regular
```

## Dcoument

In my `*.tex` document I'm using the following:

```
\setmainfont[Path=/absolutePathToUserAccount/.fonts/]{IBM Plex}
```

## Error

Xelatex produces the following error:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
!
! The font "IBMPlexSans-Regular-" cannot be found.
!
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
!
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

## Notes

- I've tried multiple combinations *IBM Plex, IBMPlex* and so forth and I keep arriving at the same error

Comment: Specifying font by its filename (`IBMPlexSans-Regular.ttf` instead of `IBM Plex` in your case) works for me.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan It works, I would suggest that you make it answer.

Comment: I don't fully understand the rules of selecting fonts, so I'd rather not. Let's wait for someone who does.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan Thanks for your contribution any way, it worked fine.

Comment: Good to hear that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Sergei Golovans comment:
Giving a `Path` argument explicitly requests to select the font by filename, so you have to use the filename `IBMPlexSans-Regular.ttf` instead (You can omit the extension `.ttf`, but I think this that just looks confusing)

On the other hand `fc-list` lists the font, so you can access it by fontname without specifying a `Path=` at all.
Just write

```
\setmainfont{IBM Plex}
```